# Regex: Get a month of each line

Tags: regex, linux, cut

I have a comma delimited log file. I need to get the month of each line. The date is in the third column of the file in the following format: 2016-07-11 02:11:43.

The following command will extract the whole date of the third column.

```
cut -d', ' -f3 logFile > newlogFile
```

How can i add a regex to this command to get just the mouth, instead of the whole date? (2016-07-11 02:11:43 --> 07).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead of `cut` and use `split` to parse `month`:

```
awk -F ', ' '{split($3, a, /[- ]/); print a[2]}' logFile > newlogFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need an extra character `cut` command

```
cut -d',' -f3 logFile|cut -c6-7 > newlogFile
```